# Replace single quote with two single quotes in a string using c++

Tags: c++

The below function is working as expected. But I think I can do it in an efficient way.

```
input = "Hello' Main's World";
```

Function Return Value "Hello'' Main''s World";

```
string  ReplaceSingleQuote(string input)
{

int len = input.length();
int i = 0, j =0;
char str[255];
sprintf(str, input.c_str()); 
char strNew[255];

for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) 
{
    if (str[i] == '\'') 
    {
        strNew[j] = '\'';
        strNew[j+ 1] = '\'';
        j = j + 2;
    } else
    {
        strNew[j] = str[i];
        j = j + 1 ;
    }
}

return strNew;

}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: in term of performance you cannot do much better, only micro improvements. Maybe in terms of code quality.

Comment: It's not safe to use `sprintf(str, input.c_str())` in place of `strcpy()` - there could be format specifiers in the string.  If you really want to use `sprintf()` instead of `strcpy()` try: `sprintf(str,"%s",input.c_str())`

Comment: @Chad: `std::replace` won't work here, because it only replaces single elements with other single elements.  It cannot change the size of the string.

Comment: However, `std::string::replace` would work, but managing the insertion point indexes/iterators would make it about as complex to use as original code is. It might be more efficient though.

Comment: @Michael Burr, `string::find` would help with that. Just check if there is an apostrophe left in the string, and then use the index returned by `find` to put in `replace`

Comment: @MichaelBurr `std::string::replace` does the job in place.  If you don't have to do it in place, you can generally find a better solution.  In this case, it might be worth using a two pass solution, using `std::count` to determine how much larger the destination has to be, rather than trying to grow it dynamically.

Comment: The whole function is just undefined behavior waiting to happen.  It will only work if `input.size + std::count( input.begin(), input.end(), '\'' ) < 255`.  Which is a very awkward pre-condition to begin with, and is absolutely not necessary.

Comment: Thaks all. The question is efficiency of the method. Let me  try to implement all your valuable comments to make my application stable and  maintain the code redabilty

Answer (score 3):

```
boost::replace_all(str, "'", "''");
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html

Comment: I am not using boost libraries

Comment: @kanden: So?  You're free to copy them, they're open source. http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp

Comment: That's actually a very good suggestion.  Something like `replace_all` is likely to be generally useful.  Because it's more general, it's likely to be less efficient than something more specialized, but until the profiler proves that this is a bottleneck, I'd go for it.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley - Yes Boost is useful, but you don't have to use a whole library instead of the resident algorithms for only one method.

Answer (score 2):

James Kanze's answer is a fine one. Just for the heck of it, though, I'll offer one that's a little more C++11ish.

```
string DoubleQuotes(string value)
{
    string retval;
    for (auto ch : value)
    {
        if (ch == '\'')
        {
            retval.push_back('\'');
        }
        retval.push_back(ch);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a `std::stringstream`:

```
string  ReplaceSingleQuote(string input)
{
    stringstream s;
    for (i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++) 
    {
        s << input[i];
        if ( input[i] == '\'' )
           s << '\'';
    }
    return s.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibility (that will modify `input`) is to use [`std::string::replace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) and [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find):

```
size_t pos = 0;
while (std::string::npos != (pos = input.find("'", pos)))
{
    input.replace(pos, 1, "\'\'", 2);
    pos += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is:

```
std::string
replaceSingleQuote( std::string const& original )
{
    std::string results;
    for ( std::string::const_iterator current = original.begin();
            current != original.end();
            ++ current ) {
        if ( *current == '\'' ) {
            results.push_back( '\'');
        }
        results.push_back( *current );
    }
    return results;
}
```

Small variations might improve performance:

```
std::string
replaceSingleQuote( std::string const& original )
{
    std::string results(
        original.size() 
            + std::count( original.begin(), original.end(), '\''),
        '\'' );
    std::string::iterator dest = results.begin();
    for ( std::string::const_iterator current = original.begin();
            current != original.end();
            ++ current ) {
        if ( *current == '\'' ) {
            ++ dest;
        }
        *dest = *current;
        ++ dest;
    }
    return results;
}
```

might be worth trying, for example.  But only if you find the original
version to be a bottleneck in your code; there's no point in making
something more complicated than necessary.

Comment: +1: Yours is the only method in my tests that actually beats `boost::replace_all` in terms of runtime efficiency.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I presume you mean the second method.  (The first will run a lot faster if you do a `results.reserve()` with size I calculate in the second.  The trick in the second, and with the `reserve` is to never copy the data more than once, and never do more than a single allocation in the string.)

Comment: Actually, both.  The first ran ~twice as fast.  And the second ~(5-6) times as fast.